# Calling a REST API with Api Id and key using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, api-key

I am trying to send a request to get a token to an API.

```
curl -X POST "https://base_url/token"
    -H "accept: application/json"
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ "appId": some_id, "appKey": some_key}"
```

This is what I did but I keep getting `400 error` response:

```
import requests
headers = {'accept': 'application/json', "Content-Type": "application/json"}
method = "POST"
data = {
    "appId": api_id,
  "appKey": api_key
}

rsp = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

This gives me a `400 error - Bad Request failed to read HTTP message`.
In addition, please can anyone explain what `-H` and `-d` mean? I guess `-H` means headers?

Comment: yes thats where I go the error message Bad Request failed to read HTTP message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`json` parameter instead of data](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.request). It should contain *A JSON serializable Python object to send in the body of the Request.*

```
rsp = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, json=data)
```

Comment: do you also have a reference where I can find all these short forms like -H, -d, -u etc?

Comment: @JA-pythonista Yes, You can find it on curl documentation [here](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can send you request with **`.post`** method if you want to send your payload as *data*:

```py
rsp = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```